# Jw player with google analytics

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I am using Jwplayer 6.9

I have free account.

I am trying to get video analytics using integration with google analytics.

I am following below mentioned link for this

[https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1417179-integration-with-google-analytics#fndtn-code][1]

But , I am not able to see analytics in my jw player's dashboard and also not getting it in my google analytics dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade to JW7. GA integration is supported in all versions of JW Player 7, including Free.